# Model/Eloquent error after doing a migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've maid a fresh install of Laravel 4, and after doing a migration of my databases, I get this error :

`\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php  line 56
Error: Call to undefined method User::newQuery() in D:\xampp\htdocs\start\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php line 56`

My `User` model is not modified (Laravel original), I just created some migrations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you call a migration class `User`, or with a same name of one of your models ?
I know it is a really dumb mistake, but the first time with a fresh install, I've did that ... and had the same error.

Composer autoloads migrations/seeds classes with your controllers and models, so your `User` model could be overloaded by a migration/seed class.